# Deleting multiple rows based on row number(s)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I want to delete rows according to the row number passed in from a WinForm. Of course, the output of the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation will always update when you delete a row, so row number will change too, therefore I want to do this in one shot rather than a loop.

I have this code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_Record (@RowNum INT)
AS     
  ;WITH REC_ROW AS
  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Record Number]) AS RN
        FROM User_Data
  )
  DELETE
    FROM REC_ROW
    WHERE RN IN (@RowNum)
```

And when I type:

```sql
 exec Delete_Record @RowNum = '1,2'
```

It produces the error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int.

If I change `@RowNum INT` to `@RowNum  varchar(max)`, it will just produce the error message:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

When I hard-code the values:

```sql
;WITH REC_ROW AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Record Number]) AS RN
        FROM User_Data
)
DELETE
  FROM REC_ROW
  WHERE RN IN (1,2)
```

It will successfully delete the row 1 and 2. The question is how can I integrate this in a stored procedure and input the `'1,2'` to pass to the `IN` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to be passing more complex strings than `1,2` you may want to consider using a table-valued parameter (TVP).

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Integers AS TABLE
(
  RowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Now you can create your stored procedure and pass in a DataTable or other collection from your application without ever bothering with constructing comma-separated strings or trying to break them apart.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Delete_Record
  @RowNums dbo.Integers READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ;WITH REC_ROW AS (...your CTE unchanged here...)
  DELETE REC_ROW
   FROM REC_ROW INNER JOIN @RowNums AS r
   ON r.RowNumber = REC_ROW.RN;
END
GO
```

If you really want to use a split function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
   @List      VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  RETURN 
  (  
    SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
    FROM ( SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')) AS a 
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i));
GO
```

Now your stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Delete_Record -- always use a schema prefix!
  @RowNums VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ;WITH REC_ROW AS
  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Record Number]) AS RN
        FROM dbo.User_Data
  )
  DELETE REC_ROW
    FROM REC_ROW 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(@RowNums, ',') AS r
    ON r.Item = REC_ROW.RN;
END
GO
```

But I guarantee you the TVP will perform better.

Comment: where should I put the CREATE TYPE dbo.Integers part? Should it be inside the Create Procedure part? I tried it and it says Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: @CaressCastañares, run it as a one time separate command.  it sets up the "type" of table parameter: `dbo.Integers` which you then use within your procedure.

Comment: @Caress no, you create the TYPE *once*, not inside the stored procedure. Consider it equivalent to creating a table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it works great!
To summarize what I did.. first, I create the Integers data table type. Second, I use the code for getting a DataTable (the second one on your answer). After creating the stored procedure, (On my WINFORM ---> ) I created a DataTable with name Integers and column RowNumber of type Int32. I populated it. Lastly, I called it using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameters and SqlReader. hooray thank you very1000x much!

Answer (score 0):

This expression does not do what you think it does:

```
 WHERE RN IN (@RowNum)
```

It is looking for cases where `@RowNum` is `'1,2'`.  And this causes the problem, because `'1,2'` cannot be converted to an integer.  You have declared the parameter an integer when you define the procedure, but then call it with a string.

You can do what you want with:

```
WHERE ','+@RowNum+',' like '%,'+RN+',%'
```

The extra commas ensure that "1" doesn't match "10".

EDIT:

There are essentially three approaches (that I can think of) for handling a string of comma delimited integers as real integers (which is better because the query will use integers).

One is to use the `split()` function, which returns a table of the elements of a delimited string.  You can google for various implementations of it.

The second is to use dynamic SQL.  This is fine for queries that do not need to be instantaneous.  It can incur additional overhead in compiling the query, which may be noticeable in transactional systems.

The third is to use recursive CTEs to parse the string.  I would probably use this method for a stored procedure.

Comment: this will not work. row "1" or "2" will never be like `%,1,2,%`.  The error is that `1,2` is not an `int`.  make the parameter a varchar and use a split function on it, then join in your delete to those split rows.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would like to use the LIKE command but I see that problem will be produced. Is there any way that it will search exact numbers and not just searching for any similarities?

Comment: @KM, may you create a sample code for this? Even if it is the Split function that you are saying, this will be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: @CaressCastañares, just search for `sql server split function`, here is a great reference: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html